# How can I know if my counter will be already going to limit?

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there a way to know if my counter will be already be equal to its limit?

```
var counter = 2;
var question_length = 3;
```

so if my counter is already 2, I just want to print something like `Only one more question` before it reach the counter 3.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Use a loop and a conditional like greater than, equal to, or less than.

Comment: i have that loop sir, but it is only displaying the ```only one more question``` when the counter already reach to 3. I like to display it before it even reach the question_length

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an if conditional:

```js
var counter = 2;
var question_length = 3;

if(counter === question_length - 1){
    alert('Only one more question')
}
```

Comment: it will be better if we do `if(counter == 2){}` right?

Comment: not exacty, in this case the OP stores a question_length into a variable to handle a max limit, and then compares to the counter of loops.

Comment: yes, the question_length is always changing depends on how many question there is.